# Sell content / templates in the Mac App Store

Tags: macos, app-store, keynote

We currently sell a set of keynote templates from our own website - would like to distribute via the Mac App Store. What we currently sell is a DMG that has a set of keynote files in it. Any ideas on if we can / the best way to sell this through the App Store?